# How to extract rows and columns from a 3D array in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I wanted to do the following indexing operation on a TensorFlow tensor.
What should be the equivalent operations in TensorFlow to get `b` and `c` as output? Although `tf.gather_nd` documentation has several examples but I could not generate equivalent `indices` tensor to get these results.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a=np.arange(18).reshape((2,3,3))

idx=[2,0,1] #it can be any validing re-ordering index list

#These are the two numpy operations that I want to do in Tensorflow
b=a[:,idx,:]
c=a[:,:,idx] 

# TensorFlow operations

aT=tf.constant(a)
idxT=tf.constant(idx)

# what should be these two indices  
idx1T=tf.reshape(idxT, (3,1)) 
idx2T=tf.reshape(idxT, (1,1,3))

bT=tf.gather_nd(aT, idx1T ) #does not work
cT=tf.gather_nd(aT, idx2T)  #does not work

with tf.Session() as sess:
    b1,c1=sess.run([bT,cT])

print(np.allclose(b,b1))
print(np.allclose(c,c1))
```

I am not restricted to `tf.gather_nd` Any other suggestion to achieve the same operations on GPU will be helpful.

## Edit: I have updated the question for a typo:

old statement: `c=a[:,idx]`,

New statement: `c=a[:,:,idx]`
What I wanted to achieve was re-ordering of columns as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done with [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather), using the `axis` parameter:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(18).reshape((2,3,3))
idx = [2,0,1]
b = a[:, idx, :]
c = a[:, :, idx]

aT = tf.constant(a)
idxT = tf.constant(idx)
bT = tf.gather(aT, idxT, axis=1)
cT = tf.gather(aT, idxT, axis=2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    b1, c1=sess.run([bT, cT])

print(np.allclose(b, b1))
print(np.allclose(c, c1))
```

Output:

```
True
True
```

Comment: Thanks @jdehesa, yes I meant `c=a[:,:,idx]`. Updated it in question.